# Bei Wörtern wie „Arztbesuch“, wie bestimmt man kontextfrei wie das Verb „besuchen“ wirkt? Wer besucht wen?

Tags: grammar, noun, compound, nominalization

<sub>(Der Titel diser Frage ist katastrophal, ich gebe zu. Hoffentlich lässt sich bald ein besserer finden.)</sub>

### Hintergrund

Die Frage ist eigentlich ein bisschen komplizierter. Natürlich wäre denn ein paar Beispiel zuerst hilfreich, die nur als Aufwärmen betrachten werden sollen.

**1. Beispiel.**

> - Beispielswort: *Arztbesuch*
> - Verb: *jemanden*<sup>(Akk.)</sup> *besuchen*

Wenn man die Bedeutung dieses Wortes nicht wüsste, wie könnte man entscheiden, ob dieses zusammengesetzte Nomen *„man besucht den Arzt“* oder *„der Arzt besucht die Patienten“* bedeutet? Besser gesagt:

- Wie könnte man entscheiden, in welche Richtung das Verb wirkt? Das heißt, ob das erste Nomen (hier *Arzt*) ein Subjekt oder ein Akkusativobjekt ersetzt?

Als Nicht-Muttersprachler hätte ich letzte Frage so beantwortet: "Rein statistisch gibt es mehr Leute, die den Arzt besuchen, als Leute, die von Ärzten besuchen werden. Daher wäre die erste Interpretation sinnvoller, d. h. Arztbesuch bedeutet *„den Arzt zu besuchen“*. *Arzt* ist hier Akkusativobjekt und das Subjekt ist stillschweigend".

**2. Beispiel**

> - Beispielswort: *Beamtenbeleidigung*
> - Verb: *jemanden*<sup>(Akk.)</sup> *beleidigen*

Der Kontext hier hilft nochmals, die Frage zu beantworten (d. h. *Beamte* ist natürlich das Akkusativobjekt). Aber man wünscht sich etwas kontextfreies. Dieses Beispiel lässt sich dann so verallgemeinern:

### Frage

(Ich will verstehen, wie und wann man zwei Nomen zusammensetzen kann. Ich muss aber zuerst verstehen, wie man die liest. Daher diese Frage.)

Man betrachte ein (hier durch **V** bezeichnetes) Verb, das ein Akkusativobjekt annimmt. Angenommen man liest ein zusammengesetztes Nomen folgender Form:

> **X**<sup>(irgendwelches Nomen)</sup> verknüpft mit **N**<sup>(einer Nominalisierung von **V**)</sup>,

kann man denken, es bedeutet einer der folgenden Sätze:

1. **X**<sup>(Nom.)</sup>  **V**  **Y**<sup>(Akk.)</sup>
2. **Y**<sup>(Nom.)</sup> **V X**<sup>(Akk.)</sup>

wobei **Y** irgendwelches Nomen ist und **V** konjugiert ist. Wenn man über kein Wörterbuch verfügt (und man will ja oft keins nutzen müssen, wenn man Deutsch lernt),

- wie kann man sich in einem kontextfreien Zusammenhang für eine Bedeutung entscheiden? 1 oder 2?

(Mein Traum hier wäre eine grammatische Regel – ich wäre allerdings hier mit guten Erklärungen zufrieden.)

Comment: Ohne die Frage vollständig gelesen zu haben: Die Bedeutung ergibt sich tatsächlich nicht aus der Grammatik, wie das ebenso gebräuchliche Wort *Krankenbesuch* zeigt, dass beschreibt, dass man jemanden beispielsweise im Krankenhaus besucht.

Comment: Ja eben, was ich befürchtet habe: Keine Regel.

Comment: Die deutsche Sprache hat halt keine ausreichend komplexe Grammatik!

Comment: Btw, after rethinking it, I am not sure what the more common meaning of *Arztbesuch* is.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz [Dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Arztbesuch) sagt *Besuch beim Arzt* sei gewöhnlicher als *Hausbesuch des Arztes.* Ich habe halt ihm geglaubt.

Comment: Vielleicht ist ein anderes/weiteres Beispielwort nötig, um besser klarzustellen, dass hier eine allgemeine Frage gestellt ist.

Comment: Bis wir ein Gegenbeispiel haben gilt aber doch: Der erste Teil ist Objekt. Arztbesuch heiß man besucht den Arzt. Das Gegenstück heißt Hausbesuch. Und Krankenbesuch heißt: man besucht den Kranken, egal wo er gerade ist.

Answer (score 3):

Die deutsche Sprache kennt keine *allgemeinen* Konventionen, die bei Komposita bestimmen ließen, was genau mit wem getan wird. Allerdings gibt es *spezielle* Konventionen, s.u.

In deinem Beispiel *Arztbesuch* ist ohne weiteren Kontext nicht eindeutig bestimmbar, wer wen besucht. Im Allgemeinen wird man, wie du richtig schreibst, annehmen, dass der Patient den Arzt besucht. Das Gegenteil ist allerdings nicht ausgeschlossen.

Um den Sachverhalt noch mehr zu komplizieren, werden bei manchen Komposita auch noch Präpositionen *impliziert* :

*Feuerschutz* könnte z.B. (manche Fälle eher theoretisch) bedeuten

1. Schutz *vor* Feuer: "Die Feuerwehr belegte die benachbarten Dächer zum Feuerschutz mit einem starken Wasserstrahl"
2. Schutz *durch* Feuer (militärisch): "Gib mir Feuerschutz"
3. Schutz *des* Feuers: "Eine Steinreihe um das Lagerfeuer dient dem Feuerschutz"

Von diesen 3 theoretischen Möglichkeiten ist an sich durch Konvention nur (2) möglich.

Nimmt man den sehr ähnlichen Begriff *Brandschutz*, ist per Konvention eigentlich nur der Schutz *vor* bzw. *bei* Bränden möglich.

Die tatsächliche Bedeutung von Komposita lässt sich also nur durch den Kontext oder durch spezielle Konventionen (falls sie denn existieren) bestimmen.

Answer (score 1):

Ich versuche es mal mit einem konkreten Beispiel:

> Ich besuche den Arzt.

Das ist ein klarer Fall mit Akkusativobjekt.

> Ich mache einen Arztbesuch.

Das scheint zunächst auch klar, ist es aber nicht: Wenn ich selber Arzt bin, kann auch gemeint sein, dass ich zum Patienten gehe. Das scheint damit eindeutig kontextfrei nicht vollstandig definiert zu sein.

Comment: der Besuch des Arztes beim Patienten ist aber ein Patientenbesuch, vobei der Patient vom Arzt besucht wird. Von demher wäre nominalisiert etwa: Arztbesuchung das "richtige" Wort..

Comment: Der Besuch des Arztes beim Patienten ist ein "Hausbesuch", oder im Krankenhaus die "Visite".

Comment: Elena hat Recht. Eine weitere Möglichkeit wäre übrigens noch "Patientenbesuch". Ein Arztbesuch ist praktisch immer ein Besuch beim Arzt.

Comment: PS: Allerdings kann ein Hausbesuch aus Patientensicht durchaus auch mal als "Arztbesuch" bezeichnet werden. ("Seit meine Mutter bettlägerig ist, muss ich mir jede Woche den ganzen Mittwoch Nachmittag freinehmen, um den Arztbesuch abzuwarten.")

Answer (score 1):

I guess the more common case is **case 2**. However, it is not determined and both cases are possible.

In dem von PMF erwähnten Fall, dass der Arzt der Sprecher ist, könnte genauso gut von einem `Krankenbesuch` oder `Patientenbesuch` die Rede sein. Dies schließt aber wiederum den umgekehrten Fall nicht aus.

Dennoch scheint **Fall 2** näherliegend. Möglicherweise, weil das Subjekt meist aus dem Zusammenhang hervorgeht und das zusammengesetzte Nomen das Akkusativobjekt liefert.

Also consider the following examples

> Peters Selbstfindung
>   - Peter fand [wen?] (sich) selbst
>   Die Schneeaufhäufung war durch den Wind bedingt
>   - Der Wind hat [wen?] den Schnee aufgehäuft
>   Nach der Erstklässlerbelehrung brauchte Tim eine Pause
>   - Nachdem Tim [wen?] die Erstklässler belehrt hatte brauchte er eine Pause.

but

> Die Brandschutzbelehrung ist Pflicht

`Brandschutz` cannot be the accusative object, since it cannot be instructed

Answer (score 0):

Die Frage, ob man natürliche Sprachen kontextfrei dechiffrieren kann, ist eo ipso sinnlos: in der "[Chomski-Hierarchie][1]" sind kontextfreie Grammatiken (deren bestimmendes Merkmal eben die Kontextfreiheit darstellt) vom Typ 2, während deren Übermenge Typ 1 genau diese Einschränkung nicht mehr aufweist (sogenannte kontextsensitive Grammatiken). Natürliche Sprachen sind in dieser Anordnung vom noch allgemeineren Typ 0 und durch sogenannte "Phasenstrukturgrammatiken" vermittelt.

Zu verlangen, daß sich eine Typ-0-Sprache (bzw. die sie definierende Grammatik) wie eine Typ-2-Sprache verhalte, ist schon aus diesem Grunde sinnlos. Wäre das der Fall, dann wäre sie eben keine Typ-0-Sprache mehr.

Auf das angeführte Beispiel "Arztbesuch" angewandt heißt dies: natürlcih kann es beides bedeuten, "Arzt besucht Patienten" oder "Patient besucht Arzt". Das wird aus diesen Beispielsätzen klar:

> Ich muß noch den Arztbesuch abwarten, dann kann ich mich der Unterhaltung mit dir widmen.

> Ich habe noch den Arztbesuch zu erledigen, danach komme ich zu dir.

Daß im ersten Fall der Arzt zum Hausbesuch kommt und im zweiten Falle aufgesucht wird, geht nicht nur aus dem Kontext hervor - es ist auch das auszeichnende Merkmal der natürlichen Sprachen, solchen Kontext ausdrücken zu können.
[1]: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky-Hierarchie

Comment: Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "etwas ist sinnlos" und "etwas ist eo ipso sinnlos"?

Comment: Das erste Beispiel überzeugt mich nicht; typischerweise heißen die Gelegenheiten, bei denen der Arzt den Patienten besucht, *Hausbesuche*, siehe z. B. beim [VdK](https://www.vdk.de/deutschland/pages/themen/gesundheit/75869/muss_der_arzt_nach_hause_kommen_rechtsanspruch?dscc=ok).

Comment: @guidot: genau darum, daß es "typischerweise Hausbesuche heißt", geht es aber hier nicht: es geht darum, daß man selbst in diesem Falle den gemeinten Sachverhalt (zB aus der Bedeutung der Vokabel "abwarten", die anstatt etwa "erledigen" gebraucht wird) ableiten kann. Genau das können Typ-2-Sprachen (zB "regular expressions") nämlich nicht.

Comment: Was hat denn "Kontext" in Produktionsregeln von Phrasenstrukturgrammatiken mit sprachlichem Kontext, Kommunikationszusammenhang zu tun?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: "eo ipso" heißt "aus sich selbst heraus" und das ist in diesem Fall der Fall: zB ist die Frage "warum gibt es k/einen Gott" sinnlos (weil nicht beantwortbar), aber "warum ist es nachts kälter als draußen" schon aus sich selbst heraus sinnlos. Die Frage "warum gelten für Typ-2-Sprachen andere Regeln als für Typ-0-Sprachen" ist ebenso aus sich heraus sinnlos, weil diese Typ-0-Sprachen dann eben Typ-2-Sprachen wären, wenn für sie die Regeln für Typ-2-Sprachen gälten.